# Xamarin Forms Android Ad-Hoc apk update There was a problem parsing the package

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, apk

Trying to create an android autoupdater for an ahoc app in Xamarin forms.
here is my code and manifest and paths xml.

The app launches fine and i can get the updater dialog. it then seems to download the apk but when it comes to install it i get the 'There was a problem parsing the package' error.

I have tried loads of different ways to do this so some pointers would be cool.

i also tried to look in logcat in release and its saying file permission error but im not sure if this is a red herring or not.

Anyone got any ideas?

````
```
public async void LaunchActivityInAndroid()
        {


            string documentsPath = $"{Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath}";

            string m_uri = $"{GlobalVariables.ApkPrefix}{GlobalVariables.ApkDomain}{GlobalVariables.ApkEndpoint}";
            string fileName = m_uri.Substring(m_uri.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

            HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = await new HttpClient().GetAsync(m_uri);
            byte[] data = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

            string directory = Android.App.Application.Context.GetExternalFilesDir("").AbsolutePath.ToString();
            string path = Path.Combine(directory, fileName);
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(directory))
            {
                if (Path.GetExtension(file) == ".apk")
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                    File.Delete("app.db3");
                }

            }

            File.WriteAllBytes(path, data);

            Android.Net.Uri fileUri;
            if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 23) {
                fileUri = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(path));
            }
            else {
                fileUri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context as Context, Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.ApplicationContext.PackageName + ".fileprovider", new Java.IO.File(documentsPath + "/app.apk")); 
            }

            Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ActionView).SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop).SetFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission).SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask).PutExtra(Intent.ExtraNotUnknownSource, true).SetDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(promptInstall);


            //webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(DownloadProgressCallback);

        }
'''
````

Manifest

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionName="1.99" package="app" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="29" />
    <application android:label="app.Android" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" android:allowBackup="false" android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_USER_DATA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_CACHE_FILES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
</manifest>

```
````

provider paths xml

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
      name="external"
      path="." />
    <external-files-path
      name="external_files"
      path="." />
    <cache-path
      name="cache"
      path="." />
    <external-cache-path
      name="external_cache"
      path="." />
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```
````

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: have you tested your apk independently of the auto installer?

Comment: Yeah so it downloads it and i can actually see the apk in android studio's file browser, if i run the apk it'll install, i just cant get it to install programmatically without the parse error